# Infinite dimensional vector space, and infinite dimensional subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble with this question:

Let  $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space.

Prove that there exist subspaces $U_1,U_2,\dots$ of $V$ with $U_{n+1}\neq U_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $U_1\supset U_2\supset\cdots$ and $U_n$ is infinite dimensional for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By induction, you need only show the existence of one such subspace.

Comment: What is your definition for a vector space to be infinite dimensional?

Comment: @Manny sorry for late message, I am still getting my head around this concept. Perhaps it is a vector space that has infinitely many basis, i.e. $\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$ that are linear independent. Maybe someone can clarify this concept.

Comment: @QSP no problem.  As you can see below, there are various solutions depending on how you think of an infinite dimensional space (bases versus big linearly independent sets).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $v_1,v_2,\dots$ be infinitely many linearly independent vectors in $V$.

Define
$U_n:={\rm span}(v_n,v_{n+1},v_{n+2},\dots)$.

Comment: oh!! That makes things clearer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

We assume the axiom of choice, of course.

Since $V$ is infinitely dimensional, it has an infinite basis, and therefore there is a countably infinite set of linearly independent vectors, write then as $\{v_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Now you can easily find a strictly decreasing sequence of infinite sets, $A_n\subseteq\Bbb N$. Let $U_n=\operatorname{span}(\{v_k\mid k\in A_n\})$. Show that from the reverse inclusion of the $A_n$'s, the sequence of $U_n$'s is decreasing, and it is strictly decreasing because we took the $v_n$'s to be independent.

Note that by choosing your $A_n$'s carefully you can control whether or not $\bigcap U_n$ is the trivial subspace, finite dimensional subspace, or an infinite dimensional subspace of $V$.

Without the axiom of choice it is consistent that there is a vector space which is not spanned by a finite set, but every proper subset is of finite dimension, so you really have to use the axiom of choice for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is an interesting way to prove it, appreciate it.